# Social Networking Sidebar Box That Expands On Hover

Tags: jquery, hover, social-networking, sidebar, expandable

Been trying for a while to get this to work and would be grateful for any help.

What I am trying to make is the social network sidebar boxes that slide out from the edge of the screen on hover, I just don't get how to do it.

Example of what I am trying to do: http://journal.digital-atelier.com/1/

Comment: you want them to slide down the page too?

Comment: No your answer below is perfect thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example ----> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jafrisella/4CDAF/)

Here is another example with two sliding out -----> [FIDDLER 2 SLIDE](http://jsfiddle.net/jafrisella/4CDAF/1/)

Setting an Item to fixed, part off the screen, and part on the screen. Then you just animate on some event. Either `mouseenter` or `click`

Just some sample code to accompany the Fiddle Link above. Follow the Fiddle link to see more

```
$('body').on('mouseenter','#social-hover',function(){
    $('#social-hover').animate({
        left: '150px'
    },250);
    $('#social-main').animate({
        left: '0px'
    },250);
});



$('body').on('mouseleave','#container',function(){
    $('#social-hover').animate({
        left: '0px'
    },250);
    $('#social-main').animate({
        left: '-150px'
    },250);
});
```